# Printing string as integers in python 3

Tags: python, string, integer

I'm writing a program in python 3 to convert input string to integers. There is just one problem with the code. That whenever a space comes it prints -64. I've tried editing a code but it prints -64 along with the space. Any advice?

```
n = input("please enter the text:").lower()

print(n)
a = []
for i in n:
    a.append(ord(i)-96)
    if (ord(i)-96) == -64:
        a.append(" ")
print(a)
```

Thanks

```
Input: "BatMan is Awesome"
Output: [2, 1, 20, 13, 1, 14, -64, ' ', 9, 19, -64, ' ', 1, 23, 5, 19, 15, 13, 5]
```

Comment: Can you provide some sample inputs and your expected output?

Comment: @Cyber: Done, added an input and the output

Comment: @Cyber *a code but it prints -64 along with the space*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you want to convert `"abc def"` to `[1, 2, 3, " ", 4, 5, 6]`. Currently you are first adding `ord(i) - 96` to your list and then, if the character is a space, you add an additional space. You want only to add `ord(i) - 96` if it is not a space.

```
n = input("please enter the text:").lower()

print(n)
a = []
for i in n:

    if (ord(i)-96) == -64:
        a.append(" ")
    else:
        a.append(ord(i)-96)
print(a)
```

Comment: Cheers man. It worked perfectly. Yes I made that stupid mistake of adding first and conditioning later. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can check if the character is a `space` with [str.isspace()](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_isspace.htm) adding `ord(i)-96` if it not a space else just add the char:

```
n = "BatMan is Awesome".lower()

print([ord(i)-96 if not i.isspace() else i for i in n])

[2, 1, 20, 13, 1, 14, ' ', 9, 19, ' ', 1, 23, 5, 19, 15, 13, 5]
```

The equivalent code in your loop would be:

```
a = []
for i in n:
    if not i.isspace():
        a.append(ord(i)-96)
    else:
        a.append(i)
```

Comment: Doh! I was 3 minutes too slow!

Comment: Thanks boss, helps a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you were appending `ord(i)-96` to `a` before checking the condition `if (ord(i)-96) == -64`, So the correct way is to first check the condition and if it matches then append `" "` else simple append `ord(i)-96`, You can simply do the same with only one if condition and ignoring the else cause by reverting the conditional as :

```
n = input("please enter the text:").lower()

print(n)
a = []
for i in n:
    if (ord(i)-96) != -64:
        a.append(ord(i)-96)     
print(a)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also do this as a one(ish)-liner:

```
import string

n = input("please enter the text:").lower()

a = [ord(c) - 96 if c not in string.whitespace else c for c in n]
print(a)
```

Using the string.whitespace list also means that other types of whitespace will be kept, which might be useful to you?

Comment: Thanks boss! Appreciate it.